# Can I get my non-refundable fee back?

Tags: rental-property, fees, ohio

I was looking for an apartment, and you have to contact them if you are interested, which I did. Then I talked to the lady on the phone and paid a non-refundable fee. A day later she sends me the application acknowledgment about the non-refundable fee and security deposit, but by that time I changed my mind and decided not to get the apartment. Since I haven't signed the application acknowledgment and haven't signed any lease, can I get my money back?

Comment: What jurisdiction is this in? What country, what state if in the US or province if in Canada, and what city or county? Laws on rentals vary widely, and often local laws control.

Comment: Columbus, Ohio @DavidSiegel

Answer (score 1):

Non-refundable application fees are non-refundable, and they are legal in Ohio. [Here](https://www.rentprep.com/tenant-screening-news/the-landlord-guide-to-charging-rental-application-fees/) is a state-by-state summary: there is no limit on how much they can charge. [Here](https://www.rentprep.com/screening-services/ohio-tenant-screening/) is a small article on Ohio law that says this.

Comment: Its funny how "non-refundable" means non-refundable

Comment: This is the admin fee, not the application fee or security deposit, which the small article was talking about.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they call it.